# Swift: array references as object properties?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a `UITableViewController` that can display content from any of three different arrays. In Objective-C, what I would typically do is set a property on the `TableVC` that is a reference to the array to be displayed. Then the `TableVC` would not only be able to show the contents of that array, but also handle user-directed editing of the array, say, if they deleted or re-ordered elements.

The way it seems to work in Swift when I set a property on my `TableVC` to an array is that it is a *copy* of my model's array, not a reference. And while this is fine in certain contexts, in my application it seems bad for two reasons: 1) my arrays are enormous, thousands of elements, and copying  huge arrays over and over again seems wasteful; 2) small edits are tougher to handle: I have to communicate back to the model about element deletion or re-ordering and make sure my view and model arrays stay in sync.

Setting a property that's a reference to an array is what I *want* to do, but there's no such thing as an `inout` object property in Swift.

What is the correct way for me to handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift `Array`s are not actually copied every time you assign them; instead, they are *copy-on-write*. What this means is that the array is only copied when something mutates it; until that point, you only copy a reference, like with Objective-C.

With that said, if you need reference semantics, the `NSArray` class from Objective-C is still available in Swift. You can also create your own `class` type that wraps an `Array` if you prefer not to use the Objective-C bridge.